# unsupported startup parameter geqo when connecting to PostgreSQL with ODBC

Tags: python, postgresql, odbc, julia

When attempting to connect to a PostgreSQL database with ODBC I get the following error:

`('08P01', '[08P01] [unixODBC]ERROR: Unsupported startup parameter: geqo (210) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

I get this with two different ODBC front-ends (pyodbc for Python and ODBC.jl for Julia), so it's clearly coming from the ODBC library itself.  Is there a way to stop it from passing this "geqo" parameter?

An example in pyodbc would be very useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the ODBC driver tries to set the `geqo` parameter in the startup packet, but the PostgreSQL server does not recognize it.

This is bunny because this parameter is exists in all PostgreSQL versions I know, at least down to [7.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/static/runtime-config.html).

Is it possible that you are using a fork of PostgreSQL that does not have this parameter?

Another funny thing is that [this commit](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=psqlodbc.git;a=commitdiff;h=417b80db94dcd4ad8f1661509ecf5c1adcc2741dhttp://) from 2014 removes the `geqo` setting, so in recent versions of the ODBC driver it should not even be used (unless you specify it explicitly with the *Connect Settings* setting).

Maybe your problem will vanish if you use a recent ODBC driver version.

Comment: Hm, I did find it suspicious that there seemed to be so little information on this online.  If it helps, I'm in Ubuntu 16.04 and I have the following packages installed:
```
apt list -a --installed | grep odbc

libodbc1/xenial,now 2.3.1-4.1 amd64 [installed]
odbcinst/xenial,now 2.3.1-4.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
odbcinst1debian2/xenial,now 2.3.1-4.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
unixodbc/xenial,now 2.3.1-4.1 amd64 [installed]
unixodbc-dev/xenial,now 2.3.1-4.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Answer (score -1):

Config SSL Mode: allow in ODBC Driver postgres, driver version: 9.3.400